# why data i stored in cache has been removed in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

I decided to store my data for example List of country, state, city, book and other data in cache for speed of my web site but I found that when the cache item count is 10 and Cache.EffectivePercentagePhysicalMemoryLimit is 98  I add my data to cache but other data will remove.

I set cache expiration to 20 min.how should I set size of cache? how should I do with this problem? why data I stored in cache has been removed in asp.net

in below code I have set a breakpoint the method return an empty list and when I check other data like country and state they have been removed from cache

```
var cahpters= CacheData.Data.Chapter.list(bookid.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why data i stored in cache has been removed in asp.net

Objects can be explicitly taken out of the cache when:

- Explicitly by calling `Remove`
- Data expiration
- Memory consumption

  - Low priority cache data will be removed first

Most probably in your case you have **huge memory consumption** so ASP.NET decided to save memory by removing you item from the cache.

Also you **can register for removal notification** (including the reason). See more about that here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7kxdx246%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Comment: i have set data expiration to 20 min and 98% of ram is free and all priority has been set to normal but when i want to get list of chapters that i added a few seconds ago it returns free list but the Cache["MYListName"] isn't null it is free (empty) list !

Comment: Use the link I've posted to check the reason for removal :)